# Drupal: block node editing for specific user(role)

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-roles

At my Drupal 7 site every registred user can add nodes. But sometimes i'd like to put some users to group e.g. "Temp ban" and block node add/edit for this users/group.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Module [Deny Access](https://www.drupal.org/project/deny_access) is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Add another role.
Deny this role the ability to add nodes (or whatever it is you want to deny them).
Change users role to this new role.

**Edit**
Create a small module that implements [hook_menu_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu_alter/7.x) to alter the 'access callback' of the paths you want, then in your custom access callback function, return true for the roles you want and false for the roles you don't want'.

Comment: Permissions for my "temp ban" role as inheritances from "registered user" build-in role, so I can't simple "deselect" permission "add node".

Answer (score 1):

You have a lot of modules contrib for rights and access :

https://www.drupal.org/project/block_access

https://www.drupal.org/project/og

Also you have custom way :

https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/69861/how-do-i-programmatically-assign-the-access-to-a-block

Comment: I want to deny access to add/update node not access drupal blocks

Comment: It's almost same thing , OG can bring you those right gestion. Read Documentation ;)